# change a dimension name using excel report builder

Tags: excel, reportbuilder

I'm using report builder in Excel. I want to change the name of a parameter of a dimension for Adobe Analytics. I use the Device Type dimension and I have "Other", "Mobile", "Tablet", ... In AA, "Other" is the same as "Computer". I want to change "Other" to "Computer" when report builder print the information in excel. (I don't want to change manually, i want it works automatically)

Thanks

Comment: Is this actually a question about programming? It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: If Excel is only the output vector for your report generated in Adobe Analytics then the excel tag is inappropriate. If you have found a way to access the Adobe SDK using VBA I'd be most interested to see it.